# is there a version of tf.unique that behaves like the bash uniq?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like for non-consecutive identical elements in a tensor to be assigned distinct idx (i.e., second output of tf.unique). Is there a way to accomplish that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK my brain is less foggy today than usual, and here is a quick solution:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
def bash_unique_with_counts(vector):
    segment_starts = tf.concat(
        [[1], tf.to_int32(tf.not_equal(vector[:-1], vector[1:]))], axis=0)
    new_vector = tf.cumsum(segment_starts, exclusive=False)
    return tf.unique_with_counts(new_vector)

y, idx, count = bash_unique_with_counts(x)
print(tf.Session().run(count))
```

> [2 2 1 1 1]